# Why can I see some HTML5 banners locally but others not?

Tags: html, adobe, banner, banner-ads, adobe-animate

So client is wondering why is it that some the banners I've built can be seen and others not and I have no good reason. Why is it that some HTML5 banners show locally and others not? I have reviewed the code on my own banners as well as others that work locally and can't seem to find the what makes some different than the others.

Any help appreciated!

Danke!

**EDIT** Most of this code is coming out of Animate. And it is only happening some of them. I cannot see any difference in the code.

Comment: possibly ad blockers and/or blocked sites

Comment: Nope. Checked those. At least on my side and _I_ can't see them

Comment: is it random or always the same banners?

Comment: Same random banners. LIke some of them are showing and others not. And I for the life of me can't see any difference.

Comment: if it's always the same banners NOT showing then maybe it has to do with how they were rendered. If they are all rendered the exact same way them maybe try a different file format.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "rendered." These are all pumped out of Adobe Animate and the all had the same settings.

Comment: My understanding of adobe-animate was that it is used to convert old style swf files to something that is compatible with html5 as flash is no longer considered safe.  I was wondering if the banners you generated were new or converted from old, and that maybe the older, converted files render differently.

Comment: Nope. These were all built from scratch inside of animate. My ad verifier is saying:


>Why this test?
>Ads that fire the DOMContentLoaded event late stay in a 'loading' state.


>How to fix?
>Defer loading heavy JavaScript libraries until after the DOMContentLoaded event >where possible.


But they are all the same